# Yet not grasping "output variables" concept both on T-SQL and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, parameters, output

What's the deal with output parameters in T-SQL/Sql Server Manager and C#?? How the 2 combines when used with assemblies and so on?

Well I see that people puts in T-SQL stored procedures output parameters...

What's the sense of this? It seems so simple yet they managed to make it dull and complicated.

I.E:

I made a stored procedure with a select and output parameters.

What's the big deal? I execute it and see the result anyway.

What's the deal with assemblies or with calling it from C# code? I execute it and I can still manage to save all the content within datatables or stream readers without the need of output parameters....

Any good explanations??

Same goed for C#

What out parameter modified does?

I.E: a function like this FindCity(string zipcode, out string cityname)

From what I've understood, it's just that I can assing cityname without even declaring it and it will come out as a string (at least I think)

What the???
Why is that? Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: If you check MSDN it says "Declaring an out method is useful when you want a method to return multiple values."

Comment: What does that even means?
Select statements already return multiple values and in C# yo can return even 10000 return values....

Comment: You can have N number of out parameters of different types, but you can only return value from a method with specific type. Check the answer that might help you.

Comment: It is not clear if you're referring to SQL or C#. From guess I can think of the second one and yet this doesn't make any sense. Even with out parameter, you still have to return all the values you need in a SINGLE object of a single type.

Comment: `OUT` parameters are sometimes used as an alternative to multiple recordsets. For example, let's say you want to retrieve an order for a customer. There is a header with the ship-to, bill-to, ..., and the line items for the order. You could `select` the header, then `select` the line items, but since the header is always singular you could return the values as `out` parameters and return the line items as the only recordset. Other times they are used for efficiency. Instead of the overhead of returning a recordset that will always contain one row, just return the values as `out` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is true that yes, in SQL you could just use "select" to return the value as a cell, this isn't always convenient. In particular, for (say) a stored procedure that will be called from other tsql - processing the result sets when calling an so from SQL is quite tricky; contrast:

```
exec someInsertProc 123, 'ABC', out @id
```

This same pattern can also be useful for non-proc SQL, just to make it convenient and explicit, and to formalize the api.

---

In c#, you only get one return value - nothing comparable to "select". Now, you could return a complex object to have properties for multiple values, but sometimes it is more convenient to use "out" - for example:

```
int i;
if(int.TryParse(s, out i)) {
```

.       total += i;
    }

Note that "out" and "ref" are relatively uncommon - and are often misunderstood by people. But they are very useful *in some cases*.

Comment: Not undestanding anything there.

Sql explanation doesn't make any sense to me

C#: Well if you want to return some data sets just put a return statement with a datatable, a string or object array, or whatever you need.

Yet out parameter modifier is not explained

Comment: @user2212907 in c# you can only `return` one thing; sometimes you want more than one thing - the TryParse returns both "did it parse" and "the parsed value", for example - but more exotic things are possible. Returning an object array is not very discoverable - it doesn't define what comes back. "Out" *does*. Very similar in TSQL - selecting a value is not as discoverable, and is not as easy to consume (especially from TSQL itself)

Comment: Ohhh... that really cleared it out! Now I see it under the right point of view!

Just asking as bonus: Do you have any link or could you make any example where do you use this practically?

Thanks again!

Comment: @user not to hand - but again, think of any TryParse (numerics), TryGetValue (dictionary), etc api

Answer (score 0):

SQL: Used as additional means of outputting results to the caller. Say you want to see a list of records and some aggregate or some related single datum. instead of creating a column for it in the result set, you could just write it to the output variable.

C#: out params are guaranteed to be populated before the function call exits (your code won't compile otherwise). It is also a means of returning more than one object to the caller. Take a look at `int.TryParse`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't helps me....
SQL: What?? I'm not getting what you're saying. Btw what's the matter of creating columns or so? I don't really get the whole thing...

C#:

So out is just to be sure that that parameters get populated before exiting?

Btw i don't see how looking at tryparse whould help me